# tab close event

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Anyone know of a way to catch a Google Chrome Tab close event? (I see there is an extension API for this but I am wondering if there such an API for Web apps; can't find it)

Comment: You can try window.onunload or window.onbeforeunload. Created for the window but they fire when the tab is closed too.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but onunload and onbeforeunload don't work me...with those i can't differentiate between a refresh/link-click and a tab/window close

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.onunload` or `window.onbeforeunload` and if you are using `jQuery` you can use `$(window).unload`. these method get called even when you refresh the page, and you can not differentiate between unload and refresh of tab. 
 following are implementations

```
window.onunload = function(){    
 //your code
};

or
 window.onbeforeunload =function(){    
 //your code
};

$(window).unload( function(){    
 //your code
}; );
```

Comment: Not differentiating between a refresh (of link click) and a tab close doesn't work for me. I am looking for a tab or window close event exclusively. thank you though

Comment: I have faced this problem while developing an application. in my knowledge there no such a method or event.

Answer (score -1):

You can use it for close the actual tab selected.

```
window.close()
```

And you can change this function.

Comment: that is used to close a window, the question is about capturing the event when the user closes the Tab (by clicking on the close tab or using a shortcut)